# Liferay customization navigation portlet

Tags: navigation, liferay, portlet

I want to customize the Liferay navigation portlet in a jsp page but I don't know what value of `headerType` is set for `rootPage`.

I wish the header was the root of the page. I tried with:

```
#set ($VOID = $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue("headerType", "root-layout"))
```

but doesn't work....

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please elaborate as to what exactly you want to do? The question is not clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set up the portlet in the way you want it via the preferences. After that, take a look in the PortletPreferences table. There you will find the setup in an xml format. You can use this as a way to get the desired values you need for setting up the portlet in a VM template.